# How to make a single-quoted string act like a double-quoted string in Ruby?

Tags: html, ruby, string, cgi

I have a file that have an HTMl code, the HTML tags are encoded like the following content:

```
\x3cdiv data-name\x3d\x22region-name\x22 class\x3d\x22main-id\x22\x3eUK\x3c/div\x3e
```

The decoded HTML should be:

```
<div data-name="region-name" class="main-id">UK</div>
```

In Ruby, I used `cgi` library to `unescapeHTML` however it does not work because when it read the content it does not identify the encoded tags, here is another example:

```
require 'cgi'

single_quoted_string = '\x3cdiv data-name\x3d\x22region-name\x22 class\x3d\x22main-id\x22\x3eUK\x3c/div\x3e'
double_quoted_string = "\x3cdiv data-name\x3d\x22region-name\x22 class\x3d\x22main-id\x22\x3eUK\x3c/div\x3e"


puts 'unescape single_quoted_string ' + CGI.unescapeHTML(single_quoted_string)
puts 'unescape double_quoted_string ' + CGI.unescapeHTML(double_quoted_string)
```

The output of the previous code is:

```
unescape single_quoted_string \x3cdiv data-name\x3d\x22region-name\x22 class\x3d\x22main-id\x22\x3eUK\x3c/div\x3e
unescape double_quoted_string <div data-name="region-name" class="main-id">UK</div>
```

My question is, how can I make the `single_quoted_string` act as if its content is double-quoted to make the function understand the encoded tags?

Thanks

Comment: _"the HTML tags are encoded like the following"_ – may I ask why it is encoded that way? Having `\xnn` style escape sequences in your file looks like a bug.

Comment: @Stefan it is encoded from the source, I don't have access or control over it, what I'm doing now is replacing `\xnn` with the HTML tags, `CGI.unescapeHTML` is working well when the encoded HTML is inside a double qouts

Comment: I'm not sure what "encoded from the source" means, but that file is neither valid HTML nor CGI encoded HTML.

Comment: BTW, `CGI.unescapeHTML(double_quoted_string)` doesn't do anything in your example, it just returns `double_quoted_string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby's parser allows certain escape sequences in [string literals](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-String+Literals).

The double-quoted string literal `"\x3c"` is recognized as containing a hexadecimal pattern `\xnn` which represents the single character `<`. (0x3C in ASCII)

The single-quoted string literal `'\x3c'` however is treated literally, i.e. it represents four characters: `\`, `x`, `3`, and `c`.

> how can I make the `single_quoted_string` act as if its content is double-quoted

You can't. In order to turn these four characters into `<` you have to *parse* the string yourself:

```
str = '\x3c'

str[2, 2]         #=> "3c"  take hex part
str[2, 2].hex     #=> 60    convert to number
str[2, 2].hex.chr #=> "<"   convert to character
```

You can apply this to `gsub`:

```
str = '\x3cdiv data-name\x3d\x22region-name\x22 class\x3d\x22main-id\x22\x3eUK\x3c/div\x3e'

str.gsub(/\\x\h{2}/) { |m| m[2, 2].hex.chr }
#=> "<div data-name=\"region-name\" class=\"main-id\">UK</div>"
```

`/\\x\h{2}/` matches a literal backslash (`\\`) followed by `x` and two (`{2}`) hex characters (`\h`).

---

Just for reference, a CGI encoded string would look like this:

```
str = "<div data-name=\"region-name\" class=\"main-id\">UK</div>"

CGI.escapeHTML(str)
#=> "&lt;div data-name=&quot;region-name&quot; class=&quot;main-id&quot;&gt;UK&lt;/div&gt;"
```

It uses `&...;` style [character references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#Character_and_entity_references).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with HTML, `\x3c` represent the hex number '3c' in the [ascii table](https://www.asciitable.com/).
Double-quoted strings look for this patterns and convert them to the desired value, single-quoted strings treat it the final outcome.

You can check for yourself that CGI is not doing anything.

```rb
CGI.unescapeHTML(double_quoted_string) == double_quoted_string
```

The easiest way I know to solve your problem is through `gsub`

```rb
def convert(str)
  str.gsub(/\\x(\w\w)/) do
    [Regexp.last_match(1)].pack("H*")
  end
end

single_quoted_string = '\x3cdiv data-name\x3d\x22region-name\x22 class\x3d\x22main-id\x22\x3eUK\x3c/div\x3e'

puts convert(single_quoted_string)
```

What `convert` does is to get every pair of hex escaped values and pack them as characters.